# Assumptions behind multinomial logistic regression

Tags: generalized-linear-model, assumptions, multinomial-logit

What are the proper assumptions behind multinomial logistic regression? And what are the best tests to satisfy these assumptions in any statistical software? What are other suitable models, if those assumptions are not satisfied?